# Finding average value of function over given region

Tags: integration

The function is $f(x,y)=2x^3+y^2-6xy-20y-14$ and the vertices are $(-4,2), (-4,8), (8,2)$.

I got $301.56$ but I dont know if I set my integrations right. I made the first integral $8$ to $2$ and the secone $8$ to $-4$ and found the are was $36$.

Comment: I guess that you should use double integrals.

Comment: I know but I think I got the limits of integration wrong and was hoping to get help on that or confirmation.

Comment: The domain of the integration is the triangle with vertices $(-4,2), (-4,8)$ and $(8,2)$. You have to know first the equation of the line trough points $(-4,8)$ and $(8,2)$. Then the variable $x$ goes from $-4$ to $8$ and in the second integral, $y$ goes from $2$ to the line.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:
$$\int_{-4}^{\ 8}\int_{2}^{-\frac{1}{2}x+6}f(x,y)dydx$$
The rest is only "hard work"